# Can a report get manually emailed from splunk

Tags: splunk

I am testing the email configuration in Splunk and instead of waiting for a scheduled report I would like to know if there is a way to manually push the report via email.

Answer (score 0):

In the search query you can add | sendemail to="email@domain.com"